# Link a Texture to Displace Modifier using Python

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, modifiers

I can add an object to a scene, and apply a Displace modifier to it using the following code:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
```

It's also easy to change some of the Modifiers attributes, like so:

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].strength =  1
```

However, I'm not sure how to link a texture to the modifier via Python. Tried the following code:

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].texture = 'Tex'
```

But it gives this error:

```
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: DisplaceModifier.texture expected a Texture type, not str
```

Linking a texture to the modifier manually shows nothing in the Info window, so I'm not sure how to accomplish this using Python.

Comment: try bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].texture = bpy.data.textures['Tex']

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and solved it this way. I was trying to create a blobbiness effect:

Make base object:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions = 6, size = 1.0, location = [0.,0.,0.])
base_geometry = bpy.data.objects['Icosphere']
base_geometry.name = 'Base_Geometry'
```

I add this by default, you can't apply modifiers in edit mode, this assumes the object is already selected:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Make texture:

```
tex = bpy.data.textures.new("Voronoi", 'VORONOI')
tex.distance_metric = 'DISTANCE_SQUARED'
```

Make the modifier, set settings, and apply:

```
modifier = base_geometry.modifiers.new(name="Displace", type='DISPLACE')
modifier.texture = bpy.data.textures['Voronoi']
modifier.strength = -0.2
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA',modifier='Displace')
```

Hope it helps